# Why wont my code output even if i put Console.ReadLine()

Tags: c#

I tried using different compilers even internet sites for c# but nothing will output
I don't know why. This is just practise for a test in school, the idea is to use the "netherland flag" algorithm or the tricolored flag algorithm.

````
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] a = { 14, 18, 6, 4, 7, 12, 3, 9, 11 };
            int t = 0;
            int o = a.Length;
            int i = 0;
            int privremeno = 0;
            while (i<9)
            {
                if (a[i]%3==0)
                {
                    privremeno = a[i];
                    a[t] = a[i];
                    a[i] = privremeno;
                    t++;
                }
                else if (a[i]%3!=0 && a[i]%7!=0)
                {
                    privremeno = a[i];
                    a[o] = a[i];
                    a[i] = privremeno;
                    o--;
                    
                }
                if (o==i)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a[j]);
            }
        }```
````

Comment: Change `int o = a.Length;` to `int o = a.Length - 1;`

Comment: And you forgot the increment `i`. So `i` is always `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to increment your `i` loop variable so its value is always `0`.
Instead, why not use a `for` loop or a `foreach` loop since you don't really need to know what loop iteration you're on.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
```

Or use:

```
foreach ( var num in a )
```

Also, you need to change this:

```
int o = a.Length;
```

To this:

```
int o = a.Length - 1;
```

If you don't you will get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` the first time the application enters the `else if (a[i]%3!=0 && a[i]%7!=0)` branch.

Comment: Thanks a lot man!

Comment: @OneGuyFromDownTown If either Caius Jard's answer or my answer helped you, you should mark them as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

> nothing will output I don't know why.

You wrote `while(i<9)` but you don't appear to ever increment i so your loop runs forever .. the code never reaches a point where anything is output

Comment: thank you i really apreciate it!